# Why can't users receive a join link link?

Tags: github, github-actions

```
name: Invitation

on:
  issues:
    types: [labeled]

jobs:
  invite:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Invite To Organisation
        uses: actions/github-script@v6 # v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.INVITE_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            const org = 'Youth-Group';
            const { owner, repo } = context.repo;
            const issue_number = context.issue.number;
            const label = context.payload.label.name;
            const { id: invitee_id, login: username } = context.payload.issue.user;

            if (label !== '✉️ Invitation') {
              return;
            }

            const isMember = await github.rest.orgs.checkMembershipForUser({
              org,
              username,
            }).catch(() => null);

            if (isMember) {
              await github.rest.issues.createComment({
                issue_number,
                owner,
                repo,
                body: "You are already a part of New-Group!"
              });
            } else {
              await github.rest.orgs.createInvitation({
                org,
                invitee_id,
              })
              await github.rest.issues.createComment({
                issue_number: context.issue.number,
                owner,
                repo,
                body: 'Welcome to the community'
              })
            }
```

I made new github organization. I wanna send join link to users automatically.
This is my invitation workflow source code.
when someone make issue, my gmail received all inputed information. But user who made issue didn't receive join link in his gmail. I don't know the reason.

If possible, please help me step by step...